# My transferred domain name appears "cancelled" - what can I do?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

at 8/2023 I purchased a domain name `csariel.xyz` at namecheap.com, for a year. After some time, I decided to "cut the middlemen" so I transferred the domain name to its original registrar `gen.xyz`, which charges less money per year. However, when I look at my account at `gen.xyz`, I see that the domain is "cancelled":

[image]

I definitely did not cancel it, and the expiration date should have been 8/2024.

Is it normal that a domain-name appears as "Cancelled" after a transfer? If so, what can I do to un-cancel it?

Things I tried:

- Clicked the "Manage" button: I did not find there any way to un-cancel.
- Opened support tickets: no one replied even after 3 days.

What other options do I have to make my domain-name work?

- In particular, if gen.xyz ignores my support tickets and does not let me use the domain I bought, is there any place I can complain to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to ICANN through their compliance complaint page: https://www.icann.org/compliance/complaint They forwarded the complaint to the registrar, and finally - after 9 days - they un-canceled my account.

Answer (score 2):

According to whois for the domain name the domain is still registered.  The whois says

```
Domain Name: CSARIEL.XYZ
Registry Domain ID: D385005546-CNIC
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.tldregistrarsolutions.com
Registrar URL: http://www.tldregistrarsolutions.com
Updated Date: 2023-10-09T06:08:55.0Z
Creation Date: 2023-08-03T08:34:12.0Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2025-08-03T23:59:59.0Z
Registrar: TLD Registrar Solutions Ltd
Registrar IANA ID: 1564
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: transferPeriod https://icann.org/epp#transferPeriod
Registrant Organization: Ariel University
Registrant State/Province:
Registrant Country: IL
Registrant Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant, Admin, or Tech contact of the queried domain name.
Admin Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant, Admin, or Tech contact of the queried domain name.
Tech Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant, Admin, or Tech contact of the queried domain name.
Name Server: PARKING2.GEN.XYZ
Name Server: PARKING1.GEN.XYZ
```

As it appears that gen.xyz does indeed run the registry, you may have a hard time getting anyone other then them to do anything about that domain name.

Comment: If gen.xyz ignore my requests and do not let me use the domain. do I have any recourse? Is there any global authority that manages the registration of names through registrars, to which I can turn for help?

Comment: Also, I see "Registrar: TLD Registrar Solutions Ltd", This is not gen.xyz - what is it? Is it the registrar from whom gen.xyz buy the domain name?

Comment: I don't think you have any recourse other then litigation as they appear to be the people who own .xyz.   Initially I thought gen.xyz was different to the authority which is nic.xyz - but they appear more-or-less the same crowd. Outside of them you have ICANN (https://www.icann.org) but i imagine they will not be to interested in sorting out your issue as they have delegated responsibility to nic.xyz.

Comment: What does "serverTransferProhibited " and "clientTransferProhibited " mean? I have just transferred my domain.

Comment: Im not 100% sure for this registry, but (going by other registries use of that phrase) I expect that you cant change ownership or registry associater with the domain right now.  There is often a "standdown period" whrn changing registrar/owner if a domain  ame to mitigate risks of domain theft and obsale.  Its normally about 1 to 2 months after an owner or registrar change.